# GitHub API authentication with MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Tags: github, vbscript, github-api

I am trying to authenticate on the GitHub API via Basic Authentication using MSXML2.XMLHTTP. I understand that I need to pass my credentials using the Authorization HTTP header.

So this is my code, but it always returns unauthenticated. (As per the GitHub API documentation, with a 404 / Not Found). What am I doing wrong? (Obviously the code does not use my real credentials, just "user" and "password" as an example).

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "https://api.github.com/user/", False, "user", "password"
o.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=="
o.send
Wscript.Echo o.responseText
```

Comment: using your script I get {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}. If I do /users/scandox I get my details.

Comment: @DanielC The problem is as Kul-Tigin points out in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer was based on a misunderstanding, so I removed it.
Trailing slashes in Github API endpoints really matter, `/user` and `/user/` are not equal. You're getting a real `404 Not Found`, not one of Github's authorization related workaround 404 responses.
This will work:

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "https://api.github.com/user", False
o.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=="
o.send
Wscript.Echo o.responseText
```